# Using multiple modifier operations in a single update in PHP with MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to use multipule modifier operations within a single update in PHP with MongoDB?

For example, if I created the following document:

```
$doc = array(
'one' => 1,
'tags' => array(),
);
```

And then wanted to add another field ('new') and add an element to the 'tags' array, I could use the following two lines:

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=>$doc['_id']), array('$set' => array('new'=>'value')));
```

and

```
$collection->update(array("_id" => $doc['_id']), array('$addToSet' => array('tags'=>'my tag')));
```

Does anyone know it's possible to do both of these two operations in one 'update' command?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used mongo in a while, but I believe you should be able to:

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=>$doc['_id']), array(
    '$set' => array('new'=>'value'),
    '$addToSet' => array('tags'=>'my tag')
));
```

Comment: To add to this, you can definitely include multiple special commands in one. However, if the commands are being programmatically generated, you have to be wary of issuing multiple commands on the same field as this may cause some issues.